# Por que a palavra "estender" utiliza "S" e a palavra "extensão" utiliza "X"?

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica

A palavra [extensão](https://dicionario.priberam.org/extens%C3%A3o) é *ato ou efeito de [estender](https://dicionario.priberam.org/estender)*, e pelo que pesquisei (se a informação estiver correta) ambas palavras palavras tem sua origem na palavra [extendere, do latin](https://origemdapalavra.com.br/palavras/estender/). No entanto fiquei em dúvida da palavra *e**s**tender* utiliza `S` e *e**x**tensão* utiliza `X`, existe algum motivo técnico ou de evolução da linguagem que levou a essa diferença?

---

The word ["extensão"](https://dicionario.priberam.org/extens%C3%A3o) is *the act or effect of extending*, and from what I've researched (if the information is correct) both words have their origin in the ["extendere", from Latin](https://origemdapalavra.com.br/palavras/estender/). However I was in doubt about the word *"e**s**tender"* uses `S` and *"e**x**tensão"* uses `X`, is there any technical reason or language evolution that led to this difference?

Comment: O primeiro registro de *estender* para o Houaiss é de 1200 e nesta época escrevia-se já com s, até porque *x* na época tinha apenas som chiado. [Camões](https://purl.pt/1/1/index.html#/187/html) (terceiro verso), em 1500, escreveu com s.  Em 1800, um dicionário da época diziam que a palavra escrevia-se com s. Com isto eu acho, incertamente, que as pessoas começaram a escrever com s e apenas não pararam. Segundo o Houaiss, a primeira ocorrência de *extenso* é de 1400, de *extensão* é de 1600, e de *extensivo* é de 1700. >>

Comment: >> Ainda, se eu não me engano, a época de 1400 é a transição entre quando se escrevia mais ou menos como se falava e quando se escrevia etimologicamente. Mais aquilo é um chute.

Comment: Ver [este artigo](https://veja.abril.com.br/coluna/sobre-palavras/por-que-estender-e-com-s-e-extensao-com-x/) pode ser um metaplasmo ou uma complexa evolução diacrónica.

Answer (score 3):

O gramático e filólogo brasileiro Manuel Said Ali atribui a grafia de 'estender' ao fato de essa palavra ter entrado ainda no século 13 na língua portuguesa, quando quem sabia escrever não dava muito importância para a origem latina das palavras. Já 'extensão' entrou para o português bem mais tarde, no século 18, quando já havia maior preocupação etimológica. Ambas, no entanto, derivam do latim 'extendere'.
Baseei minha resposta em texto publicado aqui, caso haja interesse do leitor: https://veja.abril.com.br/coluna/sobre-palavras/por-que-estender-e-com-s-e-extensao-com-x/
Espero que isso ajude.

Comment: Isso explica como chegamos ao que é hoje. Mas seria interessante saber por que nenhuma reforma ortográfica corrigiu isso ainda. Puro esquecimento, será?